# Query in google sheets first result is not a date

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to query a bunch of dates and it generally works fine, except for the first result. This does not get recognized as a date.

I query the date with =query(A1:B50;"SELECT A";1) where dates are in column A.

Subsequently I use the output to create events in Google calendar, except the first result of the query doesn't get recognized as a date.

Anything I can do about that?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of cell A1? `Format > Number`

Answer (score 0):

If cell A1 contains a date and not a column heading, try:

`=query(A1:B50;"SELECT A";0)`

However, It's not clear why you're using `QUERY` and `{A1:A}` may work just fine instead.